# creating and downloading excel file from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi

I am trying to create an excel and then downloading that file to user using servlet. Excel data would be written from database based on user input. 
I am confused if multiple users request an excel file at same time and hit the servlet, how would server create 2 or more demo.xlsx files at the same time with different data?

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Demo.xlsx\"");

Comment: Consider using Apache POI, in each servlet Thread, you can create a dummy file which you can stream back to the User.

Comment: Thanks, I think it will solve the issue.